# What is the full name of the Prophet and what does his name(s) mean?

Tags: prophet-muhammad

The questions in the heading, there isn't really much more that I can.

I just realised that I only the first name of the prophet - Muhammed, and that given the middle eastern emphasis on ancestry his full name is probably much longer than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Our beloved Prophet Mohammed(Peace be upon Him)’s full name is:

> Mohammed Ibn Abdullah, Ibn Abdul Mutalib, Ibn Hashem, Ibn Abd Zanat,
>   Ibn Abd Kusay, Ibn Kilab, Ibn Murra, Ibn Kaab, Ibn Louay, Ibn Ghaleb,
>   Ibn Fihr; Fihr was the father of Quraysh and Fihr was a descendent of
>   Ismail (A.W), whose father was Ibrahim (A.W).

[Ibn](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=ibn%20meaning&oq=ibn%20mea&gs_l=serp.3.0.0l3j0i22i30j0i22i10i30j0i22i30l2j0i22i10i30j0i22i30l2.304384.305821.0.307229.7.7.0.0.0.0.163.896.1j6.7.0...0.0.0..1c.1.15.serp.1PzyR9A4x80) refers to S/O(son of)

Refer [here](http://prophet-mohammed-pbuh.blogspot.in/2008/03/prophets-birth-year-full-name.html) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad).

The name Muhammad/Ahamed [means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_%28name%29) "Praiseworthy"

Comment: I thought all praise was only for Allah?

Comment: @otyranny 0poverty: All praise for the Real of the Real belongs to Allah; the Prophet (pbuh) is praiseworthy for being Rasul (pbuh).

Answer (score 0):

Mohammed Ibn Abdullah, Ibn Abdul Mutalib, Ibn Hashem, Ibn Abdu Manaf, Ibn Qusay, Ibn Kilab, Ibn Murrah, Ibn Ka'ab, Ibn Luay, Ibn Ghalib, Ibn Fihr, ibn Malik ibn an-Nadr ibn Kinana ibn Khuzaymah ibn Mudrika ibn Ilyas ibn Madrakah ibn Madr Ibn Nizar Ibn Ma'd ibn Adnan.

Comment: Do you have a reference?

Comment: From the Book: "When the Moon Split" biography of Prophet Muhammad by Sheikh Safiur Rahman a famous writer for Seerah of the Prophet.